# Secp256k1: Does there exist an identity public key for combinations of public keys?

Tags: secp256k1, math

I am aware that the identity on elliptic curves is the infinity element.

Long shot (as it would be very useful to me): with that being said, does there exist a public key, `pk`, on secp256k1 such that, `combine(pk, x) = x for all x`?

`combine` is via (https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1/blob/cd470333351bd6d90296352f2a957f38bbdaf014/src/secp256k1.c#L725)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you pointed out, the identity is the point at infinity. It is also the only identity for addition over the elliptic curve.

But infinity is not a valid public key, for a number of reasons, and thus also not a valid input to combine.